# Cannot re-provide geolocation on google chrome IOS after the block action

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-chrome

Some of my user click on "Block" when he receive the popup "Website wants to get your location" from iOS goole chrome browser. After 2 times doing that, the browser kept that setting and he could not change it. I've tried to do the same action as he did and still cannot re-provide the location again (This problem seems much more easier on Android and other browser like Safari, Firefox). 
- My website using https. I've already tested it on an online demo https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp (I'm using the same code with this page) but it still not work. 
- Location services on chrome app, 3G, GPS, wifi already enabled(My testing device using iOS 10.2.1) 
- The document from google does not work with iOS case 
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en&oco=1 

Is there any way to change this setting on google chrome iOS? If anyone have any idea, I really appreciate about that.

(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it's that a user has unintentionally denied your app location access in Chrome on iOS and now they would like to provide it access.  I checked in Chrome on my iPhone and I don't see Google saving location access anywhere in Content Settings like they do on the desktop.  On a demo geolocation app, I was able to block the location, then reload the page to be prompted again.  Reloading the page should do it.

Comment: @Taylor Edmiston, thanks for your answer, you understand it correctly. You are right, I tried it on other website (which has location service) and it prompted again after reload. However, after I deny it on the 2nd time, no more prompt message appear. I've just add this case to the question above